# How to convert a plain JavaScript object to a File object?

Tags: javascript, json, file-upload, meteor

I have a situation where I need to store file information (a `File` object) in a variable, but I'm required to `JSON.stringify` it first. This doesn't work on `File` objects:

```
> JSON.stringify(new File([], null))
« "{}"
```

So what I need to do is, take a file that a user uploaded, convert it to a plain object, store it in string format, and then later be able to pull that string, `JSON.parse` it, and convert it back into a `File`. Converting it into a plain object is simple enough, but getting it back to a `File` object is something I've  been unsuccessful at finding any way to accomplish.

Added clarification:

So let's say I've copied the properties of my `File` into a plain object:

```
{
  "lastModified": 1443077616000,
  "lastModifiedDate": "2015-09-24T06:53:36.000Z",
  "name": "Action Items.zip",
  "size": 3619135,
  "type": "application/zip"
}
```

I just need to convert this back into a `File` object.

Comment: Are you using localStorage?

Comment: Nope, not using LocalStorage

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a string, then?

Comment: It's outside the scope of this question, but to answer your Q: I'm using a Meteor ReactiveDict, which stringifies all its contents.

Comment: Again, outside the scope of the question. I tried to keep the question as simple as possible: I've got an object, need to convert it to a `File` object. It's because I have an uploader library that absolutely requires a `File` object to send to Amazon S3.

Answer (score 2):

base on this comment ([How to convert a plain JavaScript object to a File object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812690/how-to-convert-a-plain-javascript-object-to-a-file-object/32812868#comment53462202_32812690)) you just need a string

Use the FileReader API to transform the File into a DataURL

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();

// onload needed since Google Chrome doesn't support addEventListener for FileReader
fileReader.onload = function(evt) {
    // Read out file contents as a Data URL
    var result = evt.target.result;

    // do whatever with RESULT
    // JSON or whatever

};

// Load blob (File inherits from BLOB) as Data URL
fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Use this function https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js/blob/master/src/filer.js#L131-L158
to transform the DataURL back to a File.

```
/**
 * Creates and returns a blob from a data URL (either base64 encoded or not).
 *
 * @param {string} dataURL The data URL to convert.
 * @return {Blob} A blob representing the array buffer data.
 */
dataURLToBlob: function(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
        var parts = dataURL.split(',');
        var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
        var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

        return new Blob([raw], {
            type: contentType
        });
    }

    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;

    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], {
        type: contentType
    });
}
```

(you can replace Blob by File everywhere, since File inherits from Blob)

HERE an example of how I can take a file that was dropped by a user, convert it into a base64 string, save it (no localStorage because sandboxing) and, later, take back the string and convert it back to the file that was sent by the user.
Isn't it what you want ?

```js
var drop = document.getElementById('drop'),
  transform = document.getElementById('transform');

 drop.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
 });

 var originalFile = null;
 drop.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     originalFile = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
     console.log('originalFile', originalFile);
     fileToURLData(originalFile);
 }, false);

    var storage = {};
 function fileToURLData(file) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  // onload needed since Google Chrome doesn't support addEventListener for FileReader
  fileReader.onload = function(evt) {
      // Read out file contents as a Data URL
      var result = evt.target.result;

      /*localStorage.setItem('file-data', JSON.stringify({
       dataURL: result,
    name: file.name,
       lastModified: file.lastModified,
    lastModifiedDate: file.lastModifiedDate,
    type: "image/jpeg"
      }));*/
          storage = JSON.stringify({
       dataURL: result,
    name: file.name,
       lastModified: file.lastModified,
    lastModifiedDate: file.lastModifiedDate,
    type: "image/jpeg"
      })

      console.log('File dataURL',result);
      // do whatever with RESULT
      // JSON or whatever


      transform.className = 'show';
      drop.className = 'hide';

  };

  // Load blob (File inherits from BLOB) as Data URL
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }

 function dataURLToFile(dataURL, name, data) {
     var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
     if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
         var parts = dataURL.split(',');
         var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

         return new File([raw], name, data);
     }

     var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
     var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
     var rawLength = raw.length;

     var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

     for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
         uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
     }

     return new File([uInt8Array], name, data);
 }

 transform.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var fileData= JSON.parse(storage); //localStorage.getItem('file-data')),
   dataURL = fileData['dataURL'],
   name = fileData.name;

  delete fileData.dataURL;
  delete fileData.name;

  console.log(dataURL, name, fileData);
  var file = dataURLToFile(dataURL, name, fileData);
  console.log('convertedFile', file);
  console.log('originalFile', originalFile);
  console.log('originalFile === convertedFile ? ', originalFile === file);
        console.log('different files, same values');
 
  alert('DATAURL HAS BEEN CONVERTED BACK TO FILE - SEE CONSOLE');


 }, false);
```

```css
html, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    min-height: 500px;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 50px;
}
#drop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}

#drop.hide {
 display: none;
}

#transform {
 display: none;
}

#transform.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='drop'>DROP FILE HERE</div>
<button id='transform'>Transform back to file</div>
```

Comment: I edited my post above. I don't know if your answer is in the right direction. I don't actually have a data stream and I'm not handling the actual file-reading myself, I'm simply passing my `File` object to a third party library that handles the data stream and upload to S3 for me.

Comment: according to what you say in your comments : you need it as a string for Meteor (dataURL is a string) and you need to be able to convert back this string in a File (which this function let you do). If you need to do something with the plain object, you can do it parallely, but I don't know of any way to transform a plain object into a file. What I know is that dataURL is a string, and that this string can be converted back into a File

Comment: you can also strore a JSON string in meteor containing the File data that you already have + the dataURL, and use later just the dataURL to convert it back into a File and send it to S3.

Comment: The result of `JSON.stringify(convertedFileObj)` is `{"lastModified":1443077616000,"lastModifiedDate":"2015-09-24T06:53:36.000Z","name":"Action Items.zip","size":3619135,"type":"application/zip"}`. Your function above doesn't really return anything useful, there's no file data or URL in here.

Comment: The way I gave you give you a string representing a File (what you asked for) and a way to convert back this string into a File (what you also asked for).

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. Make an `<input type="file">` and use it to select a file for upload, and then look at the resulting file list (via either `event.dataTransfer.files` or `event.target.files`). What you'll see is an array of File objects that match the object in my previous comment above. It's *that* object that I'm looking to convert from File > Obj > File.

Comment: I did understand, and this is possible. See my update !